# Postgresql - Trigger function insert text with quotes (")

Tags: postgresql

I have a trigger function that insert the NEW fields to another table.

In the New row there are some fields with a few words like- No Reason
The trigger function insert this text to the table's field as **"No Reason"** - with **double quotes**,

The type of the table field is character varying(4000)

I used with `RETURN regexp_replace(v_value, '[\n\r]+', ' ', 'g' )` to remove the \n and \r but I didn't success to remove the double quotes.

```
-----------------------------Formatting Function------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION format_value(v_value text, format integer)
  RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

-- Empty Value
    IF COALESCE(v_value, '') = '' OR v_value is null THEN
        RETURN v_value;
    END IF;
-- 1 - TIME
    IF format = 1 THEN
        RETURN to_char(to_timestamp(replace(v_value, '"', ''), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'), 'HH24:MI');
    END IF;

-- 2 - DATE 
    IF format = 2 THEN
        RETURN to_char(to_date(replace(v_value, '"', ''), 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    END IF;

-- 3 - BOOL 
    IF format = 3 THEN
        IF v_value = 'f' THEN
            RETURN '0';
        END IF;
        IF v_value = 't' THEN
            RETURN '1';
        END IF;
    END IF;

-- 4 - INT  
    IF format = 4 THEN
        RETURN to_char(v_value::int,'99');
    END IF;

-- 5 - TEXT
    IF format = 5 THEN
        RETURN regexp_replace(v_value, '[\n\r]+', ' ', 'g' );
    END IF;

     RETURN v_value;

END 
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.cc_date_cleaner(character varying)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Thanks.

Comment: [edit] your question and add the **complete** code of the trigger function and the `create trigger` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that resolved my problem is:

```
RETURN REPLACE(regexp_replace(v_value, '[\n\r]+', ' ', 'g' ),'"','');
```

Thanks,

Comment: Why not `regexp_replace(v_value, '[\r\n"]', '', 'g')`?